# Listen click expanded searchview field

Tags: android, listener, searchview

Are there any listeners of click expanded searchview event in toolbar. I have searchview (`android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`) that expands when click on search icon.
I tried

```
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        controller.hide();
    }
});

searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

`searchView.setOnClickListener` seems like doesn't work

`searchView.setOnSearchClickListener` only listen  click on search icon (collapsed searchview).